# How to change scale of JavaFX applications?

Tags: javafx

I am trying to use the AsciidocFX editor on a 4K monitor and the user interface is too tiny.

[image]

I tried to play around with the settings, but it seems that it is not possible to change the scale of the UI from within the application.

Since AsciidocFX is written using the JavaFX framework, I thought that I could change the settings by modifying the `vmoptions` of the application, or by passing some flags from the command line. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

Which Java version do you use? JavaFX 9 and later should upscale on HiDPI automatically.

Also, you can try to control HiDPI scaling with the next VM parameter:

`-Dglass.win.uiScale=125%`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I am working on an Ubuntu OS, so the VM parameter doesn't work for me, as I suppose it is designated for Windows. I am using OpenJDK 11.

Comment: Not really, "win" suffix means window in general, not OS. I'll look into Linux bugs which may cause that.

Comment: -Dglass.gtk.uiScale for Linux